# Compiling g++ from source results in broken standard library. error: ‘::realloc’ has not been declared

Tags: gcc, c++, amazon-linux

I need to run on Amazon Linux but I need a recent `g++`. I compiled `g++` 5.3.0 from source following the instructions [here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-gcc-on-centos-6). The compilation ran for 13 hours on an EC2 instance and finished successfully.

I was then able to compile a small test program and run it. When I then go to compile a [larger program](https://github.com/facebookincubator/nfusr), I get errors that seem to indicate that the standard library is broken:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/basic_string.h:5251,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/string:52,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/array:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/mutex:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/condition_variable:39,
                 from ClientStats.h:11,
                 from ClientStats.cpp:10:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/cstdlib:153:11: error: ‘::realloc’ has not been declared
   using ::realloc;
       ^
```

Is there something else I need to compile or upgrade to have a working standard library?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it has been 4 years since this question was asked but I had run into this problem today. I had compiled gcc 11.2.0 from source on an old macbook pro in order to access recent C++ features. Upon including certain headers like `<algorithm>` I would get weird errors that looked just like the OP's errors.

My problem was that I had added to my C++ flags the include path `-I/usr/include`, which contains headers for my system's built-in old C++ standard headers. This was clashing with my new compiler. I resolved this by simply removing this flag - it just wasn't necessary in my case.